# How to create multiple volumes and attach to each instance via Terraform

Tags: terraform

The below code works when `ec2_instance_count = 1`

However, when `ec2_instance_count = 2` the following errors appears.

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.build_ec2_app.aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.build_ec2_app.aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume: Resource 'aws_instance.ec2' not found for variable 'aws_instance.ec2.availability_zone'
```

I believe it has something to do with the if statement `var.ec2_create_volume == "true" ? 1 : 0`

But even if I change `"true" ? 1 : 0` to `"true" ? 2 : 0` on both resources I still get an error when `ec2_instance_count = 2`

```
# Create EC2 instances
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  count                   = "${var.ec2_instance_count}"
  ami                     = "${var.ec2_instance_ami_id}"
  instance_type           = "${var.ec2_instance_type}"
  subnet_id               = "${var.ec2_instance_subnet_id}"
  key_name                = "${var.ec2_instance_key_name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids  = ["${aws_security_group.create_security_group.id}"]

  tags {
    Name                  = "${var.ec2_app_name}0${count.index + 1}.${var.ec2_tl_domain_name}"
    service               = "${var.ec2_service}"
    environment           = "${var.ec2_environment}"
  }
}

# Create EBS volume
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
  count                 = "${var.ec2_create_volume == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
  availability_zone     = "${aws_instance.ec2.availability_zone}"
  size                  = "${var.ec2_ebs_volume_size}"
}

# Attach EBS Volume
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "volume_attachment" {
  count                 = "${var.ec2_create_volume == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
  device_name           = "${var.ec2_device_name}"
  volume_id             = "${aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume.id}"
  instance_id           = "${aws_instance.ec2.id}"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that when the `count` for `aws_instance.ec2` is increased to 2, the resource attribute export changes from a string to a list, and you are still referencing it as a string. You can see more information on that [at the documentation here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#attributes-of-other-resources).

By updating the `volume_attachment` and `ebs_volume` resources to expect a list instead of a string and iterate correspondingly to the `aws_instance` resource, you can fix your problem:

```
# Create EBS volume
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
  count                 = "${var.ec2_create_volume == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
  availability_zone     = "${aws_instance.ec2.*.availability_zone[count.index]}"
  size                  = "${var.ec2_ebs_volume_size}"
}

# Attach EBS Volume
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "volume_attachment" {
  count                 = "${var.ec2_create_volume == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
  device_name           = "${var.ec2_device_name}"
  volume_id             = "${aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume.*.id[count.index]}"
  instance_id           = "${aws_instance.ec2.*.id[count.index]}"
}
```

Note that this still works correctly even when `count` is 1. A recommendation here is to also sync your `count` of the `aws_instance` resource with the `count` of the other two so that you ensure they are the same.

```
# Create EBS volume
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
  count                 = "${var.ec2_instance_count}"
  availability_zone     = "${aws_instance.ec2.*.availability_zone[count.index]}"
  size                  = "${var.ec2_ebs_volume_size}"
}

# Attach EBS Volume
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "volume_attachment" {
  count                 = "${var.ec2_instance_count}"
  device_name           = "${var.ec2_device_name}"
  volume_id             = "${aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume.*.id[count.index]}"
  instance_id           = "${aws_instance.ec2.*.id[count.index]}"
}
```

Locking the input var together ensures you will have the behavior you desire when you change the instance count and that undesired issues and side effects will not consequently arise.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below works for multiple instances across multiple az. Here **device_name** is list of string so we need to pass as many names as the number of additional volumes and **volume_count** is the length of list of number **additional_volume_size**.

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
      count             = var.instance_count * var.volume_count
      availability_zone = aws_instance.ec2[floor(count.index/var.volume_count)].availability_zone
      size              = var.additional_volume_size[count.index%var.volume_count]
    }

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "volume_attachement" {
      count       = var.instance_count * var.volume_count
      volume_id   = element(aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume.*.id, count.index)
      device_name = element(var.device_name, count.index)
      instance_id = element(aws_instance.ec2.*.id, floor(count.index/var.volume_count))
      force_detach = true
    }
```